# adding variables in the case of symmetric TSP

Tags: python, gurobi, traveling-salesman

I have to implement a symmetrical TSP. When I go to add the variables:
x = m.addVars (Costs.Keys (), vtype = GRB.BINARY, obj = Costs, name = 'x')
It gives me the error:
'list' object has no attribute 'Key '.
I have the data saved in a list, is there a way to add the variable or do I necessarily have to save the data in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Costs is a list. Typically, use a dictionary of distances, indexed by the edge pairs i,j. See the Gurobi tsp.py example code for an illustration.